# Unable to spyon click on button using jest and react testing library for a component testcase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hi I am new to React testing library, I tried to write a test case but not getting desired result in test case. Need some guidance. On executing npm run test its showing expected number of calls >=1, received number of calls 0

### Below is my code snippet------
Lgin.ts

```
import React,{SyntheticEvent} from 'react'


const Lgin: React.FC = ()=> {

const handleClick = (e: SyntheticEvent)=>{
console.log('hello');

}

return (
<>
<button  data-testid='btn1' type='button' onClick={handleClick}>hello</button>
</>
);
```

}
export default Lgin;

### Lgin.test.ts

```
 import {render,screen,fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react' 
 import Lgin from './component'

descritbe('Lgin',()=>{
  
it('check button is clicked',()=>{
 render(<Lgin />)
 const clkev = jest.fn()
 let btnObj = screen.getByTestId('btn1');
 jest.spyOn(btnObj,'click').mockImplementation(()=>clkev);
 fireEvent.click(btnObj);
 expect(clkev).toHaveBeenCalled();
 })


)


)
```

Comment: You'd better use `fireEvent.click(btnObj)` trigger the click event. And check what does the component render.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I missed out to put that line over here, editted it now. Result is same :(

Comment: Don't add spy on `btnObj.click`. Add spy on `console.log`, `jest.spyOn(console, 'log')`. Don't check click handler to be have been called or not. Check the log is print `expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the reference given by @slideshowp2 worked, also following script worked for me:

```
    const mockFn =jest.spyOn(global.console,'log').mockReturnThis()
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("loginbutton"))
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled()
```